# Numpy Error: only size-1 arrays can be converted to python scalars when I use math.exp

Tags: python, numpy, math

```py
import numpy as np
import math

x = np.arange(-5, 4.9, 0.1)
Graph3 = 2 * math.exp(-x**2)
```

This results in:

```
Error: only size-1 arrays can be converted to python scalars
```

When I run this code I am getting this error. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The command `np.arange` outputs a `np.ndarray` type, which is numpy's default array object.

Python's standard library `math` does not know how to interface with `np.ndarray` objects. The fix is to use `np.exp` instead of `math.exp`.

```py
Graph3 = 2 * np.exp(-x**2)
```